# Build report with changeable default parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a SSRS report with default parameters. If all parameters have a valid default value, the report runs automatically when it is first viewed. However, after autorunning in this way, it is not possible to run the report with other values than the default parameter values. Parameter input is simply hidden.

I would like to create a report that always runs with one parameter (eg. "friday"), but after running gives you the option to change that parameter (eg. to "monday") Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify available values in the below window (right click your parameter and properties).  The list can be hard coded or retrieved from a dataset.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this fixes it. I have set available values (a list, retrieved by a query), and a default value. However, the dropdown menu for picking an available parameter value is never shown. The report just autoruns with the default value.

Comment: Go to the general tab on above screen.  You will see a section called "Select Parameter Visibility".  Make sure this is set to Visible.

Comment: They are set to visible. If you remove the default parameter they become visible, it's just that adding a default parameter completely removes the option to select a parameter. Maybe this is intended behaviour (that default parameters and regular parameters can't be combined, but I don't think it should be...)

Comment: @Iain Can you provide a screenshot illustrating how the parameters look when the report is run?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this: it turns out that parameter input is not impossible after generating a report with default parameters, the UI element is simply shrunk to a thin line, that can be expanded by clicking on it. I'm afraid the solution is that simple, and I feel silly that I overlooked it (although it is kind of hard to notice).

I will accept GrandRalph's answer as it was the most usefull.